# How to unload the script so that every time the component is mounted, it is loaded again

Tags: vue.js

How to unload the script so that every time the component is mounted, it is loaded again.

```
<template>
  <div id="root">
    <component :is="App" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineAsyncComponent, ref, onMounted, onUnmounted } from 'vue';

const App = ref(null);
onMounted(() => {
  App.value = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('editor/App'));
});

onUnmounted(() => {
  App.value = null;
});
</script>
```

Code like in my example does not do this. The component is unmounted, but the file is not reloaded during subsequent mounting.
This is the code from the config:

```
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require('webpack').container;

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: 'consumer',
        filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
        remotes: {
          editor: process.env.FRONTEND_EDITOR_URI,
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What exactly to do expect to happen when a script is unloaded? Could be XY problem

Comment: That it will be reloaded on the next mount. It may not need to be unloaded. But how to make it load every time you mount. What is XY?=)

Comment: Consider explaining your case in details rather than addressing potentially wrong solution. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . What do you mean by reloaded and unloaded? What is the current behaviour and what is the expected one? It sounds like JS file could be cached, and that's primarily server-side problem, but loading a script on every mount is totally different thing and it's not common.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The problem is that the microfrontend script keeps its state and is not reloaded.

Comment: That's why it's XY problem. Unloading a script that wasn't suited to be used in component-based app way you use won't probably do any good. It's unknown in which way it keeps the state. The problem needs to be addressed in whole

Comment: Thx! I will think about a solution